# jquery event handlers on a page with angular.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have a page running with angular.js, and has some `ng-scope` classes and `ng-click` attributes on various `<tr>` elements.

We would like to use something like greasemonkey to add functionality to the page after the fact.  Specficially, on some `<td>` elements we want to append text on either a click or mouse enter.

I've tried using `click` and `mouseenter` event handlers with jQuery and nothing appears to fire.  (Attaching to a `<div>'s` `mouseenter` and `click` handlers does fire them however.)

My knowledge of angular is limited and I'm not sure if attaching an `ng-click` attribute to an element interferes with adding jQuery handlers to other elements within it?  If so, could I add to the `ng-click` handlers in some way?  If so, how?

Comment: I would suggest delegating events off of `document` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's an order of events type issue since you're probably loading elements dynamically on the page.

Likely your jQuery click logic is executing on the page ***before*** the elements really exist.

Try, for example sake, attaching your event to the document so that all ***future*** matching elements get the event.

```
$(document).on("click", "#yourSelector", function(){
    // Do something.
});
```

Comment: That did the job.  This page has a hefty load time --you can feel the processing as it draws graphs-- etc, so I think you're correct.  Thanks!